# Why gdalinfo don't show subdatasets in sentinel-2 imageries?

Tags: gdal, sentinel-2, gdalinfo

[In this article](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html) Sentinel-2 products have 'Subdatasets' where I can open the 10 meters resolution bands. But in some imageries there isn't this sector.

For example in imagery ['de4388a9-13e1-4c5c-affe-515c9a2277c5'](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('de4388a9-13e1-4c5c-affe-515c9a2277c5')) isn't subdatsets.

```
gdalinfo S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20170602T042051_R135_V20151209T075322_20151209T075322.xml

Driver: SENTINEL2/Sentinel 2
Files: S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20170602T042051_R135_V20151209T075322_20151209T0
75322.xml
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT=7.5755689585225765
  DATATAKE_1_DATATAKE_SENSING_START=2015-12-09T07:53:22.031Z
  DATATAKE_1_DATATAKE_TYPE=INS-NOBS
  DATATAKE_1_ID=GS2A_20151209T075322_002420_N02.04
  DATATAKE_1_SENSING_ORBIT_DIRECTION=DESCENDING
  DATATAKE_1_SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER=135
  DATATAKE_1_SPACECRAFT_NAME=Sentinel-2A
  DEGRADED_ANC_DATA_PERCENTAGE=0
  DEGRADED_MSI_DATA_PERCENTAGE=0
  FOOTPRINT=POLYGON((...))
  FORMAT_CORRECTNESS_FLAG=PASSED
  GENERAL_QUALITY_FLAG=FAILED
  GENERATION_TIME=2017-06-02T04:20:51.000005Z
  GEOMETRIC_QUALITY_FLAG=PASSED
  PREVIEW_GEO_INFO=Not applicable
  PREVIEW_IMAGE_URL=Not applicable
  PROCESSING_BASELINE=02.04
  PROCESSING_LEVEL=Level-1C
  PRODUCT_START_TIME=2015-12-09T07:53:22.031Z
  PRODUCT_STOP_TIME=2015-12-09T07:53:22.031Z
  PRODUCT_TYPE=S2MSI1C
  PRODUCT_URI=822_2017-06-02T03_59
  QUANTIFICATION_VALUE=10000
  RADIOMETRIC_QUALITY_FLAG=PASSED
  REFERENCE_BAND=B1
  REFLECTANCE_CONVERSION_U=1.03002388757155
  SENSOR_QUALITY_FLAG=PASSED
  SPECIAL_VALUE_NODATA=0
  SPECIAL_VALUE_SATURATED=65535
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

In this imegery( scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('ab904126-1e9f-44d4-a4ca-a86deb3e86a6') ) gdalinfo works fine and there is subdatasets.
Sorry about my english.

GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23